# Does i need vpn to update/upgrade packages on fedora or debian if https is configured in sources file

Tags: linux, wifi

Does i need vpn to update/upgrade packages on fedora or debian if https is configured in sources file ?
Can packages be replaced by malicious ones through wifi attacks like fraggattacks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Debian and Redhat/Fedora use gpg to ensure that package integrity.

- [RPM and GPG: How to verify Linux packages before installing them](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rpm-gpg-verify-packages)
- [SecureAPT](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) for Debian.

In short, this ensures that only packages signed by keys that shipped with your distro, or by keys added by you, will be installed. Delivery method is not important, as the *downloaded* package is verified. A MiTM attack serving you a false package will not succeed, as it will fail signature validation.

So in short, you don't need TLS to protect your download against malicious packages. However, TLS protects against some other risks. Without TLS, a MITM attack can hand you old, vulnerable, versions of packages when you install additional packages, or deny updates by not offering them.